# Dynamically Adding Strings to char Pointer with malloc and realloc

Tags: c, linux, dirent.h

I am trying to read a directory using the Dirent Header file in C.

I am having trouble storing the file names inside the given directory inside a char array.

the code is below.

```
char * FileNames;

while ( ( DirentPointer = readdir(DirectoryPointer) ) != NULL) {

    strcpy(&FileNames[Counter], DirentPointer -> d_name);

    Counter++;
}
```

When I run the application I am getting a segmentation fault. I think that the strcpy is faulting the application because of memory allocations.

Can anyone tell me how malloc and realloc can be used to dynamically add memory allocation to the FileNames Char *?

Comment: I think the first issue you have is that `FileNames` is just an array of char. You need and pointer to pointers of chars to store all the names `char **FileNames;`

Comment: I am new to the language to be honest. If I create a pointer to pointers how can I reference the array in the strcpy method? Should I use the &&?

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial, it might be useful: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would produce undefined behaviour or most probably crash. That's because `FileNames` is a pointer to a character, not to a memory buffer to copy your strings into and the function `strcpy` does not do bounds checking for the buffer being copied into. So `strcpy` will try to write into the memory you have not allocated for the purpose. You need to allocate memory to copy the file names first.

```
#define MAX_FILE_NUM 1000

char *FileNames[MAX_FILE_NUM] = {0}; // initialize to NULL
int Counter = 0;

while((DirentPointer = readdir(DirectoryPointer)) != NULL) {
    FileNames[counter] = malloc(strlen(DirentPointer->d_name) + 1); // + 1 for the null byte
    // check for NULL
    if(FileNames[i] != NULL) {
        strcpy(FileNames[i], DirentPointer->d_name);
        Counter++;
    }
    else {
        // handle the NULL case
        // maybe try malloc again 
    }
}

// after you are done with the FileNames

for(int i = 0; i < Counter; i++) {
    free(FileNames[i]);
    FileNames[i] = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am still trying to figure out how to use pointers. I tried your code but I am having an incompatible pointer type error in the strcpy method.

Comment: I am assuming `DirentPointer->d_name` is a `char *`. Could you please tell me what type it is?

Comment: @Andrew sorry there was a mistake in my code. I have updated it. Please try again now and let me know if it works.

Comment: Ohh Sorry, Yes d_name is a char *, but FileNames[Counter] is a char ** right?

    /usr/include/string.h:125:14: note: expected ‘char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
 extern char *strcpy (char *__restrict __dest, const char *__restrict __src)